# Clear Hive Box without the encryptionCipher

Tags: flutter

I'm building a chat app for the web. I cache the chats with Hive and encrypt the Box with the UID of the logged in user.

If another user logs in, I want to clear the Box and fetch data from the cloud data store for the new user. However, assuming I do not know the UID of the previously logged in user, how do I clear the old Box? AFAIK, I need to open the Box and then clear it, and I cannot open the box without the previous encryptionCipher.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use box.clear();
Or box.values.toList().clear();

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code, it is better:

`box.deleteAll(box.keys);`

Comment: Your answer should include an explanation of the code so other users know **why** it is better than the alternatives in this instance.